# I need to overwrite an existing Python installation in ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

and thanks ahead of time.

I am relatively new to Linux and am using Ubuntu 12.04.3.  Basically, I've been messing around with some files trying to get Django to work.  Well, I though I should do another install of Python2.7 for some reason.  Stupidly, I manually installed it.  Now when I open the Python shell and do 'import django', it can't be found.

I just want to go back to using the Python that was on Ubuntu by default, or overwrite the one I installed manually with one using apt-get.  However, I am unable to figure out how to do this nor have I found a question that could help me.

Any help is much appreciated.  I've been working on this for 6 hours now...

--EDIT--

Ok well I'm just trying to go ahead and have the PYTHONPATH look in the right place. I've seen in other posts that you should do this in the ~/.profile file.  I went into that file and added this line

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

"import django" is still coming up with "no module found"

I tried doing "import os" and then "os.environ["PYTHONPATH"], which gave me:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "", line 1, in 
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in **getitem**
   raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'

As far as I can tell, this means that I do not have a PYTHONPATH variable set, but I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong.

--ANOTHER EDIT--
As I am not a very reputable member, I am not allowed to answer my own question before 8 hours from my original question, so I am putting it as an update.

Hey guys, thank you all for the quick responses and helpful tips.  What I did was open a python shell and type:

> > > sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')

and it worked!

I should have done this from the beginning instead of trying to overwrite my manual Python installation.

Once again, thank you all for the help.

I feel so relieved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your path - python not finding django becuase it doesnt know where to look for it. Look up issues regarding path and see if those help.

Comment: Yea I noticed that I could do that and I was contemplating do so.  However, I'm just wondering if this could cause a problem in the future when I need the PYTHON_PATH to find something and it can't because I installed it manually.  That is the reason why I was hoping there was a way for me to overwrite my manual installation of python with one using apt-get or something similar

Comment: In adding stuff to your python path you shouldnt delete anything - you just append it on so that it knows to look there also.
What youre suggesting might happen though - because its a new install it might not know where to look for other stuff but once again you could add that to your path. 
I'm a noob myself so I'm not too knowledgeable on this stuff. 
What I would recommend doing is setting up a virtual environment if your going installing new python instances. Theres a tutorial here http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: This tutorial is more to do with running things on flask (a lightweight python server) but he sets it all up in a virtual environment first so that its all packaged together and doesnt interfere with other installs.  
Bit off the point but might help for the futture

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you want to be using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), it was designed specifically to avoid this sort of problem :)

Comment: Yea I was actually going to use that.  However, I was told not to do that and I stupidly listened to his advice. (Neither of us know much about Django).  But you live and you learn :)